# Android Studio Pixel 2 virtual device - Pixel 2 AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm looking for Pixel 2 virtual device. I've updated to the latest Android Studio RC2 version but seems like Pixel devices are the last ones in the list.

[image: Android VD list]

I do know I can create custom hardware profile with Pixel 2 resolution, but Pixel 2 display has rounded corners.

[image: Pixel 2 device]

So was Pixel 2 virtual device released? Any links to download Pixel 2 hardware profile?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: For now I created a virtual device myself with the device specs of the Pixel 2 XL: 6,0 inch screen, 1440 x 2880 resolution, 4 GB ram, at least you can test screen issues. No rounded corners though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you are already aware by now, but just in case, Android Studio versions >= 3.0.1 include the Pixel 2 and Pixel 2 XL hardware profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gjudkins update. Yep, I finally find the native implementation for Pixel 2 virtual device in Android Studio 3.0.1.

Weird that it doesn't render content with rounded corners though.

[image: Result view]